# VB.Net readonly property being automatically initialised without Get code execution

Tags: vb.net, properties, initialization

I don't understand this, please help. Here is my code:

```
Class MyCookie
    Private _CookieName As String

    ReadOnly Property CookieName As String
        Get
            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_CookieName) Then _CookieName = "Test"
            Return _CookieName
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

I put a breakpoint inside the property Get procedure. When I initialise MyCookie class, MyCookie.CookieName already has "Test" in it but the breakpoint is never hit!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What other value would the debugger display for that property? The debugger has to execute the property to get a value to display in the IDE but your application hasn't executed the property so the breakpoint isn't activated.  Breakpoints are only activated by YOU executing the code, not the IDE.  If you were to use the debugger to watch the `_CookieName` field instead of the `CookieName` property then you'd see exactly what you would expect to see.

Comment: I'll test what you said but _CookieName is Private, the only place a value is set for _CookieName is inside the CookieName Get prcoedure.

Comment: Yeah, so? If you're watching `CookieName` in the debugger then the debugger has to execute the getter for that property to get a value.  It can't just pluck it out of the air.  If the `_CookieName` field hasn't previously been set then of course the property getter is going to set it to "Test" and then return that value.  That's exactly as you'd expect.  As I said, the reason that you don't see the breakpoint hit is that it's being executed by the debugger and not by the application.

Comment: Ah, didn't understand your answer properly this morning. After re-reading it, it makes sense to me now. I did not know this behaviour of the IDE. Thanks

Comment: I rarely make sense on the first try. ;-)